# Do I actually need to show a proof of plane ticket for applying a Schengen Visa for Germany?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, international-travel, germany, schengen-visas

I am utterly confused because I see contradicting information on the internet. Some say I don't [(1)](https://www.quora.com/Do-I-need-a-flight-ticket-for-applying-for-a-German-National-Visa) ,[(2)](https://www.quora.com/If-I-dont-have-a-housing-confirmation-yet-can-I-apply-to-a-student-national-visa-in-Germany-without-accommodation-confirmation) and others say I do for [eg](https://www.schengenvisainfo.com/schengen-visa-application-requirements/). Could someone please give me the correct information backed by an authoritative source?

Note: I live in a kuwait and have an Indian citizenship

Comment: Why rely on Quora or other unofficial sites when the German embassy/consulate sites are relatively well organized and gives the requirement according to your visa type? The list can differ based on your nationality or where you are applying from.

Comment: That particular link was upvoted a lot it and also seemed so the person answering was from similar nationality as me so I thought so. @xngtng

Comment: What is the purpose of your trip to Germany?

Comment: Tourist visa for the time being @DavidSupportsMonica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL; dr**

If your trip is for tourism, you must have a "valid and confirmed flight reservation" to apply for a visa.

**More detail**

Germany is part of the Schengen Area, and [citizens of India require a Schengen visa for entry](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/en/visa-service/-/231148).

Applications for Schengen visas are to be made to the Schengen country where you'll spend the most time during your trip. Presuming that will be Germany, you must apply to the German Embassy in Kuwait for your visa. [The German Embassy in Kuwait has outsourced its visa processing to the private firm VFS Global](https://kuwait.diplo.de/kw-en/service/-/1902410?openAccordionId=item-1980528-2-panel). The cited page contains this:

> **Visa Application Center Kuwait**
>
> Short-term applications for Schengen Visas (e.g. for tourism, visits, business) for travels to Germany, Finland, Iceland or Norway are to be submitted to our Visa Service Center VFS Global Kuwait who will for your convenience ensure that all the relevant documents are included in your application...

This is followed by contact information for VFS Global Kuwait. VFS Global Kuwait's website is [here](https://visa.vfsglobal.com/kwt/en/deu/). On that page, select Apply for a Visa > Identify Visa Type. If "Tourist Vista" is the visa type, then select "Documents Required" > ["Checklist Tourist Visa - Non-Kuwaiti Nationals."](https://visa.vfsglobal.com/one-pager/germany/kuwait/english/pdf/schengen-non-kuwat-tourism-nov-2021.pdf)

That last page, in turn, contains this:

> **6. Flight booking and accommodation**:
>
> • Valid & confirmed hotel reservation incl. full address (name, street, city, zip code, contact infor- mation, booking ref.)
>
> • if applicable: Package Tours/Round Trips (reservation for each segment of stay incl. full address)
>
> • if applicable: please attach a copy of your contract/proof of property with the full residential ad- dress if you will stay at an apartment/house in Germany that you own
>
> **• Valid & Confirmed flight reservations**
>
> ...

Thus, in addition to other required documents, applicants must show "valid & confirmed flight reservations."

Other visa types may have different requirements.

Sources cited here are all primary, both German government webpages, and VFS webpages where VFS is the actual provider of German government services.

Comment: Damn. The amount of false information on the Internet. Thanks tho. I was losing my brain trying to understand this.

Comment: @Aplateofmomos The requirements are different for varying kinds of visas, a student visa does not require proof of accomodation, you were just misunderstanding the Quora answers.

Comment: The quora answer did not explicitly state that it was talking about Student Visa so I suppose the real issue is that it was absolutely unclear @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: @Aplateofmomos This one does, and is a link you provided: https://www.quora.com/If-I-dont-have-a-housing-confirmation-yet-can-I-apply-to-a-student-national-visa-in-Germany-without-accommodation-confirmation

Comment: Yes but the issue was it contradicted with 1 @Dr.Snoopy

Comment: I'll note that he Quora answer you're talking about is six years old. Things can change over time. The Answer reflects today's reality.